# Calling directive function from controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this controller

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'restService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, restService) {                    
        $scope.saveTask = function (workflow, form) {
            if (form.$valid) {
                if (workflow.isSaved == false) {
                    angular.toJson(workflow);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('saveOrDelete', 1); /*HERE IS CALLING*/
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

And my directive with `saveOrDelete` function:

```
.directive('logWork', [function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.saveOrDelete = function(option) {
                switch (option) {
                    case 1: {
                        angular.element(element).find('.note-input').css('width', '85%');
                        angular.element(element).find('.active-accept-button').css('display', 'none');
                        angular.element(element).find('.active-delete-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
                    } break;

                    case 2: {
                        angular.element(element).find('.note-input').css('width', '70%');
                        angular.element(element).find('.active-accept-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
                        angular.element(element).find('.active-delete-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
                    } break;
                };
            };
        },
                templateUrl: Global.directives.worklogblock
    };
}])
```

And I have a problem, I can't call my `saveOrDelete` function from controller. How I can do this? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your directive you need to listen to the `saveOrDelete` event your emitting in your controller. You then have access to the arguments passed into the `broadcast` or `emit` and can work with them.

```
$scope.$on('saveOrDelete', function(event, option) { $scope.saveOrDelete(option); });
```

Be aware anything in your application will be fired if they are listening to this event.

Not too sure if your aware of the difference between `broadcast` and `emit`, there listed in the docs below. They can give strange behavior if your not aware, thought i best mention it also.

EDIT: On a side note your wrapping your element in `angular.element` i don't think this is entirely necessary. If you have JQuery included before angular then the element object will be a full JQuery object. If not it will be a JQueryLite object.

Emit and broadcast docs, you will also find the docs on listening to events (`$on`) on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Answer (score 0):

You are using the $broadcast wrong.

```
$scope.$on('saveOrDelete', function(event, option) {
  switch (option) {
  case 1: {
    angular.element(element).find('.note-input').css('width', '85%');
    angular.element(element).find('.active-accept-button').css('display', 'none');
    angular.element(element).find('.active-delete-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } break;

  case 2: {
    angular.element(element).find('.note-input').css('width', '70%');
    angular.element(element).find('.active-accept-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
    angular.element(element).find('.active-delete-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } break;
};});
```